# python-3.4 Scapy sniffing

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, packet-sniffers

I have an error when running this script:

```
from scapy.all import *
sn = sniff(filter="http", count=30)
wireshark(sn)
```

This is the error:

```
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
WARNING: Please, report issues to https://github.com/phaethon/scapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "arp1.py", line 2, in <module>
sn = sniff(filter="http", count=30)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 566, in sniff
s = L2socket(type=ETH_P_ALL, *arg, **karg)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scapy/arch/pcapdnet.py", line 276, in __init__
self.ins.setfilter(filter)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scapy/arch/pcapdnet.py", line 236, in setfilter
error("Could not compile filter expression %s" % f)
NameError: name 'error' is not defined
```

When running this script, everything works:

```
from scapy.all import *
sn = sniff(filter="icmp and host 66.35.250.151", count=4)
wireshark(sn)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Scapy* uses the [*BPF* syntax](http://biot.com/capstats/bpf.html) for filtering. This syntax doesn't support specifying `"http"` as the filter in order to filter *HTTP* traffic.

---

However, it is possible to filter all traffic destined to or originating at port 80, which is commonly used for *HTTP*. The link above proposes the following filter:

> To capture all *IPv4 HTTP* packets to and from port 80, i.e. print only packets that contain data, not, for example, *SYN* and *FIN* packets and *ACK*-only packets. (*IPv6* is left as an exercise for the reader.)
>
> > `tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)`

[This *stackoverflow* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11781000/3903832) supplies a clear explanation of the technical details that stand behind this filter. In a nutshell, it calculates the length in bytes of the application layer payload carried by the packet and verifies that it is not 0 (and thus, positive):

- *IP* packet length - *IP* header length - *TCP* header length != 0

Since the file `/etc/services` assigns port number 80 to the service name `http` it is possible to rewrite the previous filter as follows:

> `tcp port http and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)`

For completeness, it is recommended to filter port 8080 as well (`http-alt` in `/etc/services`).

---

Of course, this doesn't guarantee that the filtered traffic is indeed *HTTP* traffic or that unfiltered traffic doesn't contain *HTTP* traffic. More sophisticated filters are required for such an endeavour. They would examine the content of the application layer payload in an attempt to deduce the underlying protocol in use.

A simple google search would present several alternative filters for all kinds of purposes, depending on your end-goal. [This *stackoverflow* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16610385/3903832), for example, suggests filters for the basic methods of *HTTP*: one for the *HTTP GET* method and another for the *HTTP POST* method.

Comment: I know understand why! Do you know what 'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)' means tho (a filter, yes but what does it do and is it necessary)?

Comment: I've updated my question with some clarification regarding the rationale of the filter and with [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11781000/3903832) to a more detailed explanation.